# Error handling of scatter gather in Mule 4

Tags: exception, routes, error-handling, mulesoft, mule4

Please let me know if my approach is correct.
Mulesoft v4.4

My inbound is a Queue, When the message is read from queue - it has to be transformed and published to other queue (for downstream system).
In this application - I had implemented custom exception strategy and all is going good.

Here comes the new request, once the message is read from inbound queue , same message should be processed to 2 downstream systems

1. Same as earlier - transform & process the message to target queue
2. Transform and invoke different APIs.

To achieve the above, I designed my application as described in flow-Diagram, using scatter gather.
I'm trying to handle all the exceptions of both the scenarios in my custom exception strategy

But, Here say if no any exceptions occur in route 0 and some exceptions occur in route 1.
I'm getting mule-Composite-Error, I know it is expected.,

But I need to handle each exceptions thrown individually like API errors (For route 1) and MQ errors( for route 0). I have handled each of these exceptions, but error-output of scatter gather is composite-Error. I need my original errors to propagate out of scatter gather, so that corresponding errors are handled. Please let me know how can I achieve it?

Please note, I have wrapped each route of scatter gather in try scope and in error handling I have user on error propagate.

[image: Flow Diagram]

Error Logs:

```
{
  "ErrorPayload": {
    "Errors": {
      "ErrorCode": "500 : TE",
      "ErrorType": "COMPOSITE_ROUTING",
      "ErrorDescription": "Exception(s) were found for route(s): \r\n\tRoute 1: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.DefaultMuleException: Bad Request Sent. Validate the request Payload.",
      "ProductNumber": "K85965",
      "SourceSystem": "PDAL",
      "AdditionalInfo": {
        "inboundAttachmentNames": [
          
        ],
        "inboundPropertyNames": [
          
        ],
        "outboundAttachmentNames": [
          
        ],
        "outboundPropertyNames": [
          
        ],
        "payload": {
          "failures": {
            "1": {
              "suppressedErrors": [
                
              ],
              "childErrors": [
                
              ],
              "errorType": {
                "identifier": "BAD_REQUEST",
                "parentErrorType": {
                  "identifier": "ANY",
                  "namespace": "MULE"
                },
                "namespace": "API"
              },
              "cause": {
                "verboseMessage": "\r\n********************************************************************************\r\nMessage               : Bad Request Sent. Validate the request Payload.\r\nElement               : Validate-API-Response-Code-Sub_Flow/processors/1/route/2/processors/0 @ product-to-oms-mp-v1-qvc-us:product-to-sims.xml:137 (Raise 400 error)\r\nElement DSL           : <raise-error doc:name=\"Raise 400 error\" doc:id=\"0244da40-9961-4f31-8109-02fecbb33bde\" type=\"API:BAD_REQUEST\" description=\"Bad Request Sent. Validate the request Payload.\"></raise-error>\r\nError type            : API:BAD_REQUEST\r\nFlowStack             : at Validate-API-Response-Code-Sub_Flow(Validate-API-Response-Code-Sub_Flow/processors/1/route/2/processors/0
```

Here actual error is under payload.failures => but i need the error to be propogated as errors

Comment: Questions in Stackoverflow need to be more detailed. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It should include input data and concrete examples of the actual results and expected results.